# How to write a test for Plug error handling

Tags: testing, error-handling, elixir, plug

I'm trying to use `Plug.Test` to test error handling implemented with `Plug.ErrorHandler` -- with `assert conn.status == 406` and alike.

I have the `defp handle_errors` (containing a single `send_resp` statement) and it seems to be called, however, my tests fail with the same exception still (as if `handle_errors` has no effect).

A reference to a sample advanced Plug (not Phoenix) app will also be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use [assert_error_sent/2](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/1.5.6/Phoenix.ConnTest.html#assert_error_sent/2) to assert that you raised an error and it was wrapped and sent with a particular status. Match against its `{status, headers, body}` return value to assert the rest of the HTTP response met your expectations.

```
response = assert_error_sent 404, fn ->
  get(build_conn(), "/users/not-found")
end
assert {404, [_h | _t], "Page not found"} = response
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this (not tested):

```
defmodule NotAcceptableError do
  defexception plug_status: 406, message: "not_acceptable"
end

defmodule Router do
  use Plug.Router
  use Plug.ErrorHandler

  plug :match
  plug :dispatch

  get "/hello" do
    raise NotAcceptableError
    send_resp(conn, 200, "world")
  end

  def handle_errors(conn, %{kind: _kind, reason: reason, stack: _stack}) do
    send_resp(conn, conn.status, reason.message)
  end
end

test "error" do
  conn = conn(:get, "/hello")

  assert_raise Plug.Conn.WrapperError, "** (NotAcceptableError not_acceptable)", fn ->
    Router.call(conn, [])
  end

  assert_received {:plug_conn, :sent}
  assert {406, _headers, "not_acceptable"} = sent_resp(conn)
end
```

Comment: That's exactly what I tried before posting this question, but it's not a solution.

Comment: Try overriding the `handle_errors/2`, and use the given `reason`. That passes the test for me (see edited above).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but matching against a formatted string is not a solution for me. I was expecting to be able to match the actual error type or something.